# Python equivalent to wordpress sanitize_text

Tags: python, django, wordpress, slug, stop-words

I need the Python equivalent to wordpress sanitize_text

for title:

```
'mygubbi raises $25 mn seed funding from bigbasket co founder others'
```

wordpress gives

```
"mygubbi-raises-2-5-mn-seed-funding-bigbasket-co-founder-others"
```

Python slugify gives

```
"mygubbi-raises-2-5-mn-seed-funding-from-bigbasket-co-founder-others"
```

I have used python-slugify Python library.

Am I supposed to just to remove words like from, in, and, to. where can I get those stop words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [python-slugify](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify) library has a `stopwords` parameter which can be used in conjunction with `nltk` as follows:

```
from slugify import slugify
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

text = 'mygubbi raises $25 mn seed funding from bigbasket co founder others'
print slugify(text, stopwords=stopwords.words('english'))
```

This would print:

```
mygubbi-raises-25-mn-seed-funding-bigbasket-co-founder-others
```

After installing `nltk` you can install additional corpora, one of which are the `stopwords`. To do this run their built in download utility as follows:

```
import nltk

nltk.download()
```

[image: NLTK download helper]

Select `Corpora`, scroll down to `stopwords` and click the `Download` button.

Answer (score 1):

There is a python module called nltk. This offers you the possibility to do exactly this.

http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/NLTK/tokenization_tagging_NLTK.php

Just scroll down a little on this website to find the headline "Removing Stop Words". There are examples of how to do this using this module.